# Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself

Tags: npm, gulp

Quando eu executo:

> npm install --save-dev gulp

Acontece o erro:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" "gulp"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ENOSELF

npm ERR! Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
```

Onde o **importante** é:

```
 npm ERR! Refusing to install gulp as a dependency of itself
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri que não posso chamar meu projeto no package.json de gulp, então mudei para gulpProject

```
{
  "name": "gulpProject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1"
  }
}
```